# I Want to Download ann App That is Free and is for android 1.6, i have android 2.1 and it says its not compatible

Tags: applications, google-play-store, 2.1-eclair, 1.6-donut, zte-racer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why are some Apps on the market incompatible with my device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/15814/why-are-some-apps-on-the-market-be-incompatible-with-my-device)

Thats it.
I Wanna Download This App
https://market.android.com/details?id=com.projectx.android.ScouterLite&feature=search_result

And i Have an ZTE Racer With Android 2.1

What's wrong?

Comment: try contacting the developer and asking for the APK file (since the app is free, hopefully he'll accommodate you).

Comment: I have a Motorola XT300 with 2.1 and when I try to install the ING DIRECT Canada app I get the same error. Driving me nuts.

Answer (score 3):

It could be all kinds of things, Google won't (yet) tell.  I'm annoyed about that myself (having bought a Samsung Galaxy 5 two weeks ago).  Posted an item to the Google's Android Help forum, but no official response (yet...).

I'd be surprised, though, if it was the carrier.  Too low camera resolution sounds more plausible (I suspect that's why I can't install Google Goggles, the Galaxy 5 camera does 2 MP only).

But... only the developer of the app could tell you which requirements they specified in the manifest.

A bit of background: an app developer can specify features her app requires.  Like "device needs a camera".  Or "device needs at least X x Y screen resolution".  The market checks this list against the device you want to install it on, and... in your case, they don't match.

Comment: Probably the screen resolution - this device seems to be 240x320, half the size of the original android phones which are themselves small by today's standards.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably your carrier.  Developers can choose which carriers to allow for their apps.  As well, Google just announced the ability to allow specific devices only (not sure whether it's implemented yet).  [Other ZTE Racer owners have reported such Market issues](http://www.google.ccm/search?q=zte+racer+market).