# "device isn't compatible with this item" - why?

Tags: google-play-store, compatibility

I would like to download and install [this app](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.softwarecandy.outsmartmike.googlefree&hl=en) on my *Samsung Continuum SCH-I400* running Android **2.2.2** but instead of a `download` button, the Market displays an error message that reads:

> Your device isn't compatible with this item.

I checked the minimum requirement for this app and it says Android **2.2**. Why would Android Market flag it as incompatible with my phone?

Is there a way to get from the Android Market more details about this incompatibility?

What do I need to add or change in my *Samsung Continuum SCH-I400* to make it compatible?

Comment: Related/similar: [Why are some Apps on the market be incompatible with my device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/15814/why-are-some-apps-on-the-market-be-incompatible-with-my-device)

Comment: @eldarerathis Thanks for that link. The answer there, however, doesn't help my particular case at all. I am still clueless as to what I need to change in my phone to make it compatible with that app. +1.

Comment: You probably can't change anything to make it compatible, short of making the Market think it's another type of phone.

Comment: @Al Everett Thanks. I can't understand why the Market is so **mysterious** about this. That's very disappointing. +1.

Comment: You could always contact the app author directly. There's an email address associated with every app and any developers I've ever contacted have been very responsive. It's entirely possible that the dev screwed up the definition of the app.

Comment: I just downloaded this same exact app from [CNET](http://download.cnet.com/Outsmart-Mike/3000-7483_4-75451977.html) and it works like a charm. So my device is perfectly compatible with this app. It looks like a bug in the Android Market.