# Tagged for Android not compatible with Mi320?

Tags: google-play-store

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why are some apps on the market incompatible with my device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/15814/why-are-some-apps-on-the-market-incompatible-with-my-device)

I use CSL Mi320 and I tried to download 'Tagged for Android'. The problem is that it stated that the app is incompatible with my phone. Why is that?

Answer (score 2):

Could be a number of things.  App developers can set the minimum requirements for their apps which the Market will check before letting you download and install them.  The phone's OS version could be less than what the app requires, the screen resolution could be too low (320x480 of your phone as can be seen on the bottom of [this page](http://mobilemegamall.com/goods/4574),) the phone could be missing some hardware component required by the app (e.g. GPS, front-facing camera, etc.)  The best way would be to contact the developer with your phone's specs, and inquire as to why their app is incompatible.