# How does an app such as "Plants vs. Zombies Great Wall Edition" get downloaded or purchased on Android?

Tags: applications, google-play-store, amazon-appstore

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why are some apps on the market incompatible with my device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/15814/why-are-some-apps-on-the-market-incompatible-with-my-device)

I read that Plants vs. Zombies Great Wall Edition is available on May 18, 2012, but on an ASUS Transformer T300, searching on Google Play, Amazon App Store, or QQ game install app, all gave nothing.

Does someone know how to purchase or download it?

The related news is:

http://www.techinasia.com/pvz-great-wall-edition-and-kingdoms/

http://usa.chinadaily.com.cn/weekly/2012-05/11/content_15265342.htm

Comment: It's very likely that the app has not been listed as compatible with your device and/or it is not available in your region.

Comment: Have you tried searching from a PC rather than your Android device? For instance, searching from _my_ Android tablet returns nothing. But searching from a PC (whilst logged in) finds _something_ but tells me that, "This item cannot be installed in your device's country." - so it at least gives me a clue.

Comment: Yeah i wonder if it is Apple app store, then it can be purchased at exactly one place... I am happy and the company that earned the extra money should be happy too

Answer (score 2):

Apparently it is not compatible with Asus Transformer after ICS update. Source:

- [Amazon page for the game](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0052UZIFA)
- [XDA thread about this problem](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1518353)
- [Wikipedia page for Transformer Prime](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asus_Eee_Pad_Transformer_Prime)

Plants vs. Zombies is listed as incompatible for my Transformer too (on Google Play).