# Google Play Store App error

Tags: google-play-store, 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I upgraded my Samsung Galaxy Note GT N7000 from Gingerbread to ICS. (Had used the software update option:

```
Settings → About Phone → Software Update → Update[check for updates]
```

And thus the Google Play Store app also got updated to the version 3.8.17 which is compatible with ICS.

But the app on my phone plus the Play website apparently still have the old Android version. As a result apps which are now compatible with ICS (for example Adobe Photoshop Touch) are still:

1. Shown as incompatible on the website and
2. Not even displayed in the app on the phone.

**I have already tried:**

1. Clear cache and data of the app;
2. Uninstall all updates of the app;
3. Installed the app version 3.8.17 again via another source on the net but it did not help. So now I also, don’t have the original app provided by Samsung.

**Question:** How do I solve this? Is there someway I can download the app via Samsung without installing the whole of ICS again?

Comment: Did these apps appear as compatible with your device *before* you did the update? There are many other factors that determine compatibility, your version of Android is not the only one, so is there any evidence to assume that your version of Android is the problem? Related: [Why are some apps on the market incompatible with my device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/15814/why-are-some-apps-on-the-market-incompatible-with-my-device)

Comment: I'll take the example of Adobe Photoshop.  Adobe Photohsop Express is compatible with Ginger Bread. Whereas Adobe Photoshop Touch is compatible with ICS but not Ginger Bread. I installed PS Touch via some other source on the net and its working fine. PS Touch is not being displayed by the app on my phone and the website is showing it as incompatible with my phone. Earlier on when I had Ginger Bread then PS Touch didnot work on my phone (Parse Error).

Comment: That doesn't answer my question in my previous comment. Did the Play Store show it as compatible with your phone *before you updated to ICS*? Installing from a 3rd party source may not be relevant (it could be bypassing whatever requirements your phone does not meet), especially if it was not an officially provided download.

Comment: That's what I'm saying. Ps Touch is not being displayed by the app on my phone in the search results. And the website displays it as incompatible. Before the update and also after the update.

Comment: I understand what you're saying, but I don't think you're quite understanding what I'm asking you. **Before** you updated your phone to ICS, when it was still running Gingerbread, was it possible for you to install PS Touch from Google Play? (I'm guessing no, it requires 3.1 now and I think it always has)

Comment: It has never been possible to install PS Touch from Google Play (before or after upgrading). Yes, it requires 3.1+ But for the sake of experimenting I had tried installing it (via another source - had downloaded the .apk file) on GingerB and had got "Parse Error". But now it is working fine after upgrading to ICS.