# Why is Kivy Launcher giving "your device isn't compatible" with Nook HD+?

Tags: google-play-store, nook-hd

When I bought my Nook HD+ a week after Google Play was enabled for it, one of the first apps I installed was the Kivy Launcher. It worked great for a few times, then stopped working mysteriously - wouldn't even generate a log file. I finally decided to uninstall it and reinstall again.

Now when I go back to the Play Store, it shows a message under the app icon:

> Your device isn't compatible with this version.

I have no idea why it wouldn't be compatible, since it worked the first time I tried it. Is it possible that B&N black-listed it? What other conditions would generate this message?

Comment: The generic Q&A is likely relevant: [Why are some apps on the market incompatible with my device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/15814/why-are-some-apps-on-the-market-incompatible-with-my-device)

Comment: @eldarerathis, that's very relevant, thanks. Unfortunately it doesn't really answer the question.