# Google Play does not recognise updated firmware

Tags: updates, device-firmware

I have updated the firmware on my Samsung GT-s5570 to Android 2.3.4. Google Play does not recognise that I have upgraded and will not install apps that are for 2.3 or higher. Still thinks phone is on 2.2.

HELP PLEASE

Comment: How are you certain that is the reason they won't install? I don't believe the Play Store gives you a specific message that tells you that your version of Android is too old. Are you sure it's not region restrictions or hardware incompatibility?

Comment: Thanks, app is a simple heater control, say needs 2.3 or higher. My phone was on 2.2 so I upgraded firmware usinh Kies no problem. Google Play it seems only recognises phone model and not firmware status if different from factory default??

Comment: Google Play should have no problem identifying your Android version. It can check that when you launch it. Again, did it tell you *specifically* that it could not be installed because your version of Android was not supported? There are many, many reasons an app may be incompatible with your device; the version of Android you have installed is only one of them. I would wager the app requires some hardware feature you do not have. See also [Why are some apps on the market incompatible with my device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/15814)

Comment: Thanks provided GPlay can see firmware version I guess you are correct. I;ll contact the developers and ask questions.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same phone and the same problem, running android 4.2 (flash), so google play does not watch your Firmware level, but your phone's name.
Just try to find your apps on the internet or try other markets (like GetJar).

Just now I was trying to find a solution for the problem :)