# Is there a way to see why an App is incompatible with your phone?

Tags: applications, google-play-store

Currently trying to install Animal Crossing, and on the store page it blocks me.

Incompatible with your device it says. I check, it needs at least android 4.3, I've got 6.0.1, so I should be good.

But it is incompatible. So is there a way to see what exactly is the trouble making the app unavailable for me? Like a checklist that you should have A, B and C running to be compatible, but you don't have B.

Is there a way to have more information, instead of this generic error message?