# How to install an app consisting of multiple apk using the `pm` android’s command?

Tags: samsung, root-access, installation, 9.0-pie, systemless-root

In order to get a specific visa, I need to verify my ɪᴅ using a government official app. I went on the play store and it first showed as not being compatible [because it requires ɴꜰᴄ which my phone doesn’t have](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/251483/87784).

So I manually downloaded the app and obtained an xapk because the single app consists of several `.apk`. So far no problems using `adb install-multiple`. I then launched that app to verify my ɪᴅ and then the app complained it wasn’t installed from the Google’s play store.

The solution to this situation is normally to simply install the apk using `pm -i com.android.vending apk`.

But how do that when the same app ɪᴅ consist of several `.apk` ?
Please also note it uses `com.android.vending.CHECK_LICENSE` for the same purpose so that setting the installer after isn’t enough.

Comment: https://raccoon.onyxbits.de/blog/install-split-apk-adb/

Comment: @Robert but unlike stock’s android `pm`, `adb` doesn’t have a full way to fake the installer. This means the app complains I should only download it for free from Google Play for my security…

Comment: I'm afraid this looks like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/241919) where X is "How to make apps that use `CHECK_LICENSE` work when installed from APK?" while Y is "How to install multiple APK using `pm`?" since there's a possibility that *Play Store sets something on the server* when installing from Play Store, thus `pm` may be irrelevant since it will just do the same installation process like from ADB (which you have successfully done). [Your follow-up question](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/251983/44325) is perhaps a more reasonable way to solve this issue.

Comment: However, the question about installing multiple APK using `pm` itself is certainly on-topic, which @Robert 's comment has answered (the link mentioned ADB only for `adb shell`, but the main topic is using `pm`). Thus, consider trying that guide and let us know the result, or post it as a proper answer!

Comment: @AndrewT. I told in my question `adb install-multiple` is how I got the app to complain it wasn’t installed from the Google’s Play Store. The `pm`/`cmd package` tool can fake the installer, but I don’t see how to use them on split ᴀᴘᴋs… App is supposed to be started off‑line so without accessing Google’s servers…

Comment: @user2284570 according to [the official Android Developers guide](https://developer.android.com/google/play/licensing/client-side-verification#impl-lc), `CHECK_LICENSE` fetches the result of the license online from Google Play, so I'm not sure if the method to install the APK is still relevant...

Comment: @AndrewT. just start the app using the airplane mode ! As a government app, getting it is free.

Comment: Have you tried the simple command `pm set-installer "PACKAGE" "com.android.vending"`? Or just read the pm help text then you will see that `pm install-create` also has the `-i` option.

Comment: @Robert it wouldn’t modify all files unlike a clean install, and `set-installer` can’t be used as root and thus can’t be used at all (`ᴜɪᴅ 0 unsupported` error message).