# Using root, how to fake nfc support of my phone so I can install apps that requires nfc from the Google Play Store?

Tags: samsung, root-access, 9.0-pie, nfc, systemless-root

This question is an [extension of this question where I want to perform the nfc checking part at the embassy](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/251982).

Which files do I need to change in the filesystem using root so I can download apps marked as incompatible on the Google Play Store because my phone lack nfc sensors ?

Comment: For modifying the file-system you need an unlocked device and root permissions and in such a case it will be 1000 times easier to manually add the flag that the app had been installed by Play Store than faking a non-existent NFC feature. But if the app is so restrictive that it only allows installs from Pay Store then the chance is high that it also checks for root. BTW. What app in detail are you talking about? A Link to the app in Play Store would be helpful.

Comment: @Robert problem is how to tell to an app that uses `com.android.vending.CHECK_LICENSE` that it was installed from the Google’s Play store. Otherwise, I’m still using Magishide…